# table-cell width gets larger as width property gets smaller

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div style="display: table; border: 1px solid green;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 1%; max-width: 1000px; background: red; height: 30px;"></div>
</div>
```

Changing the width property has completely counter-intuitive consequences.

A bigger example of this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/8DUfr/2/. How is the width of the red rectangle calculated?

Answer (score 0):

You were using width: percentage%; in the wrong div. You put it in the parent div for each red bar. I fixed your JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/8DUfr/4/

```
<h3>1%</h3>
<div style="display: table; border: 1px solid green; width: 1%">
<div style="display: table-cell; max-width: 1000px; background: red; height: 30px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am aware that setting the width on the parent would fix it, but why does it work the way it does in the original code? Why does the parent have any width at all? What is that width based on?

Answer (score 0):

The box model in CSS has traditionally worked this way:

> Given width `w`, the actual visible width of the box is calculated by adding w to the left and right padding of the element plus the left and right border. The width specified via the CSS `width` property, in modern browsers only tells CSS how wide the content area should be. [See W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) for an example.

For illustration purposes, let's say you have the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">Something here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

The visible width of `.box` is actually: 100 + 2 * 1 + 2 * 2 = 106px. To make the box measure exactly 100px, you have to subtract 6px from the specified width to compensate.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-adjusted">Something here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box-adjusted {
    width: 94px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

With the advent of CSS3, we now have the `box-sizing` property. The value that makes the width work as we expect is `border-box`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box2">Something here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box2 {
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nnN6t/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/nnN6t/3/)

Comment: While all of this is true, it does not explain how the undefined behavior works in my example.

Comment: What exactly were you looking for? Your post asked, "How is the width of the red rectangle calculated?" Not sure what your post means by "counter-intuitive". My suggestion is to specify the behavior you're experiencing and what you expect to prevent misinterpretation.

Comment: I know how to fix this issue. My point is that this behavior is undefined by the spec, but the browser is doing *something* to create the layout. If you look at the linked jsfiddle, you'll see that lowering the value of the width will make the red bar larger, not smaller. My question is: what is the math that's happening here to make it work like that. I know how to fix it: put a width value on the parent. My question is about the exact mechanism by which it's broken.